# MySQL Foreign-Key Constraints Prevent Insert Queries in Parent Tables

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have several MySQL InnoDB tables in my Project Most queries use the primary key of the Parent table as the basis of the query, a sample of which is shown here:

```
Agreements (Parent Table)
---------------------------------------------------
ID       UnitID    Report   Protected   TenantID
---------------------------------------------------
19       288       1        0           13
20       287       1        0           9
21       286       1        0           9



Reviews (Child Table)
-----------------------------------------------------
ID    AgreeID     FrequencyID      ReviewDate
-----------------------------------------------------
10    11        4              2015-04-25 00:00:00             
14    35        4              2007-03-08 00:00:00     
15    18        4              2017-03-01 00:00:00



ActionableDates (Child Table)
------------------------------------------------------------
ID    AgreeID   CriticalDate           Note
------------------------------------------------------------
3     11        2013-04-24 00:00:00    ... yadda yadda ....
7     48        2017-11-25 00:00:00    ... yadda yadda ....
8     47        2014-05-21 00:00:00    ... yadda yadda .... 
9     14        2014-06-24 00:00:00    ... yadda yadda ....
```

The tables were migrated from MS Access and ive spent the past few months writing an application for the client which mainly reads and updates the data.
This is working fine but now when attempting to INSERT new records the foreign-key constraints are preventing any inserts of a new Agreement(the Parent Table) since there are UPDATE/DELETE CASCADE restraints on all child tables (Reviews and ActionableDates).

```
Agreements.ID -> Reviews.AgreeID
Agreements.ID -> ActionableDates.AgreeID
```

I understand the need to have these constraints for update delete operations to ensure were not left with orphan records. 
However there is no need for these contraints to 'kick' into play when inserting a new record into the Parent table, Agreements.

The logic is that the child tables have records added at any time during the lifetime of the operational application; so if adding a new agreement there probably, most certainly, will
NOT be a review record to add to the corresponding Reviews table. Same with the ActionableDates table. These 'incidents' occur any time after the Agreement (record) is created.

Are there any kind of manipulation of these MySQL constraints i can use to preserve the CASCADE ON Update/Delete but which allows me to enter a new record into the Parent table??
None of the other Actions can be set without an error : 'No Action', 'Set default', 'set Null' etc ...

Not sure why or how these restrictions worked in the original MS Access DB but they make no sense logically. Other than creating a ficticious record to the child tables???

Ive removed all foreign-key contraints for now and using Transactional PDOMySQL to define some logic.

### Edit - Agreement Table Schema

## Agreements

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| Column                      | Type                          | Nullable | Default |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| ID (PRIMARY)                | int(11)  Auto Increment       | No       |         |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| UnitID                      | int(11)                       | Yes      |         |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| Report                      | tinyint(4)                    | Yes      | 0       |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| Protected                   | tinyint(4)                    | Yes      | 0       |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| TenantID                    | int(11)                       | Yes      |         |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| RentNotes                   | longtext  utf8_general_ci     | Yes      |         |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| Dilapid                     | varchar(255)  utf8_general_ci | Yes      |         |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| AgreeDated                  | datetime                      | Yes      |         |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| AgreeStartDate              | datetime                      | Yes      |         |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
| AgreeEndDate                | datetime                      | Yes      |         |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reverse the foreign keys.

```
Reviews.AgreeID         -> Agreements.ID
ActionableDates.AgreeID -> Agreements.ID
```

The **child** tables have to point to the **parent** table not vise versa

Comment: - But that would mean if a child record is deleted remove the corresponding Agreement record! definately NOT what im looking for. there could be zero or more review and actionableDates records for each agreement.   The Agreement ID is primary-key and foreign-keys are AgreeID in child tables so they shouldnt even be updated manually since that would violate the use of primary-keys. The only valid and useful constraint seems to be ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: Your statement is half correct. Your not completely understanding your database structure. What you are saying is correct but your implementation is wrong. At least what i see from the example

Answer (score 0):

In Agreement table you have

```
---------------------------------------------------
ID       UnitID    Report   Protected   TenantID
---------------------------------------------------
```

You need to check where you get Unit ID and TenantID which may be primary keys of other tables Like "Unit" and "Tenant". In that case you need to have records in those tables then only you can refer it in this table.

Comment: Yes UnitID and tenantID are primary keys in the corresponding tables like the two child tables shown. What i dont understand is if im inserting a new record into Agreements there can be zero or more corresponding child records in any child table - howerver if Updating or Deleteing an Agreement then of course CASCADE the changes to the corresponding child tables. The mYSQL INSERT  error tells me the foreign-key constraint between Agreements.ID and Reviews.AgreeID is violated; same with ActionableDated.AgreeID

Comment: Can you post agreements table structure by viewing "SHOW CREATE TABLE Agreements". It may be helpful for further checking

Comment: Not sure how to post the table text-based like in my question in comments??

Comment: The schema does not include any constrains / foreign key references to check the error.

Comment: Yes i copied it from Adminer (not the command line) the foreign keys were shown in a seperate table before i deleted them - however when trying to recreate them icannot with this error :

Source and target columns must have the same data type, there must be an index on the target columns and referenced data must exist.
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`****dbname****`.`#sql-1568_bd`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-1568_bd_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `Reviews` (`AgreeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

i removed db name to protect client

Comment: CONSTRAINT #sql-1568_bd_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Reviews (AgreeID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
This clearly says your Primary Key ID is a child key for the Reviews(AgreeID) that what @Dilyan Trayanov says. Your ID key only should be a Primary key can't contain other reference